# What if $N$ is not normal in semi-direct product $N\rtimes H$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In classification of groups of order $n$, we always use semi-direct product. And require $N\unlhd G$, $H<G$ and so on. But what if $N$ is not normal? It seems we can still use $(n_1,h_1)(n_2,h_2)=(n_1\Phi_{h_1}(n_2),h_1h_2)$, where $\Phi_{h_1}\in \mathrm{Hom}(H,\mathrm{Aut}(N))$ to define the operation. So, if $N$ is not normal, then it may not be a problem.

Comment: But $N$ is normal in any semidirect product $N \rtimes_\Phi H$, so it is not clear what you are asking!

Comment: @DerekHolt  "We now apply Theorem 12 to classify groups of order n for certain values of n. The basic idea in each of the following arguments is to
(a) show every group of order n has proper subgroups H and K satisfying the hypoth-
esis ofTheorem 12(H$\unlhd$G, H$\bigcap$K=1) with G = H K" These words are right from Dummit and Foote's algebra. So we need to find the normal group first!!!!

Comment: But I have no idea what you are asking!

Comment: @DerekHolt For example, we classify the group of order 30 by semidirect product, we need to find the normal group N and subgroup H s.t H$\bigcap$K=1, and |HK|=30. Then we consider Hom(K,Aut(H))... My question is what if we consider the case, finding a subgroup N(not normal) and subgroup H s.t H$\bigcap$K=1, and |HK|=30. And then repeating the procedures as above

Comment: @joseph, $HK\leq G iff H\subseteq N_G(K) or K\subseteq N_G(H)$.Since you want HK to be the entire group, that would require that either $N_G(H)=G$ or $N_G(K)=G$, depending on which containment we have. This one of them most be normal in G for HK to be a group and have the same cardinality as G.

Comment: @SE318 That can't be right.  $S_n$ has exact factorizations not involving $A_n$ for $n\geq 5$.

Comment: Ahh yeah, the necessary and sufficient condition for HK being a subgroup is HK=KH. What I gave was merely sufficient. My bad!

Comment: I am looking at Dummit and Foote right now though, and even though I am wrong about the necessity of my statement, there is a good explanation as to why $K\leqN_G(H) on page 177 in the proof of Theorem 10.

Comment: You have to have a normal subgroup if you want a semidirect product. Otherwise you need to use more generalized forms such as the Zappa-Szep product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will show that if you have a semidirect product, then $N$ will be normal. Let $G=N \rtimes_\theta H$. Well consider the projection homomorphism $\pi_H:N \rtimes_\theta H \to H$, which is a homomorphism since $$\pi_H \left((n_1,h_1)(n_2,h_2)\right) = \pi_H(n_1 \theta_{h_1}(n_2), h_1h_2) = h_1h_2$$ and $$\pi_H(n_1,h_1) \pi_H(n_2,h_2) =h_1h_2.$$ It is pretty clear that (the identified) $N$ is the kernel of the projection, so $N$ is normal.

---

The short of it is that the definition of semidirect product implies that $N$ is normal in the semidirect product, so you can't have the situation you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related construction that generalizes the semidirect product that you might be hitting upon.  The basic idea is that, given finite groups $K,Q$ we wish to find all groups $G$, and injective morphisms $\phi\colon K\to G$, and surjective morphisms $\psi\colon G\to Q$ such that $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)=\ker(\psi)$.  In this case we say that $G$ is an extension of $K$ by $Q$.  We can express this in terms of a short exact sequence, but I'll skip that here (it's just a convenient graphical notation).

Note that this means that $G$ contains a normal subgroup isomorphic to $K$: $\ker(\psi)$, namely.

However, the group $G$ need not be a semidirect product. $G=K\rtimes Q$ (after a few notation abuses: I've not supposed that $Q$ is a subgroup of $G$) if and only if there is a homomorphism $\beta\colon Q\to G$ such that $\psi\beta=\operatorname{id}_Q$.  $G$ will be a direct product if there is also a morphism $\alpha\colon G\to K$ with $\alpha\phi=\operatorname{id}_K$.

Now for any such short exact sequence, there is nevertheless a morphism $\theta\colon Q\to\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ when $K$ is abelian--the basic idea being to construct it from a transversal of the cosets of $K$--such that $G$ will be determined by the data $(K,Q,\theta)$.  When $K$ is non-abelian the codomain of $\theta$ is $\operatorname{Aut}(K)/\operatorname{Inn}(K)$; the procedures are generally more complex when $K$ is non-abelian.  Much as with the semidirect product, the morphism $\theta$ effectively describes "how" $K$ is normal in $G$.

It is important to note that not every extension yields a semidirect product.  Indeed, $\mathbb Z_4$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$, but any semidirect product of those two groups has no elements of order 4 (indeed, such a semidirect product must be a direct product).  The basic reason is that there need not be a choice of coset representatives of $K$ which forms a subgroup of $G$ (isomorphic to $Q$).  The cosets themselves form the quotient group, but it is not always possible to pick coset representatives that give a group; you can do so if and only if there is a morphism $\beta$ as above.

Comment: Thank you very much! These things are very helpful!